# CakePHP includes "<!-- xxx.s -->" in AJAX response?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

Im just trying to send a simple jquery ajax request but always get the response like this:

```
""ok""< !--" 16.7154s "-->"
```

Why: `< !-- 16.7154s -->`?

My js:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: 'controller/action/' + $('#nickname').val() ,
    success: function(data) {
    alert( data ==='ok'  );

  }
}); return;
```

My controller:

```
function verifynick(){    
  $this->layout='ajax';    
  $this->autoRender = false;    
  return ('ok'); 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put the debug mode at 0.

You can do it on the fly in your action like this

> Configure::write('debug', 0);